# Scrape Facebook page and parse with php

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get a list of names and profiles that shared a particular post of a Facebook page.

I thought I could use simple html dom to parse the page with php, but with no success yet. This is my code so far:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

function scraping_shares() {
    $html = file_get_html('https://m.facebook.com/shares/view?id=10156833628051729');

    foreach($html->find('div.bn') as $data) {
        $item['name'] = trim($data->find('h3.bo', 0)->plaintext);
        $ret[] = $item;
    }

    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    return $ret;
}

ini_set('user_agent', 'My-Application/2.5');

$ret = scraping_shares();

foreach($ret as $v) {
    echo $v['name'].'&nbsp;<br>';
}

?>
```

Any help please?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What's not happening that you are expecting to happen?

Comment: I'm expecting to get the data in the "h3" element with the class "bo" that is in the div container with the class "bn" and add each to array $ret. 

$ret is Null and can not understand why.

Comment: I would imagine facebook has multiple processes in place to thwart this type of thing. For one, I'm sure a session id would be required as you must be logged in to view the page. There may also be logic for checking that the user agent is a known web browser. Plus I doubt all of the shares are going to be on the initial page load. They are probably loaded asynchronously, so doing a simple get request of the page probably isn't going to get you what you're after anyway. You will more than likely need to utilize something like the iMacros browser plugin with some custom scripts.

Comment: Yes you are right about the asynchronous loading, that is why I'm using the m.facebook, the mobile page that displays all shares at once. You are probably right in that I would need a session id of a logged in user. Thank you for your help.